# Use object state in other methods

Tags: java

I created an instance like this:

```
Dog dog1 = new Dog();
```

and two methods:

```
public void name(String name)
{
}

public int move(int distance)
{
    System.out.println("Dog has moved " + distance + " ft.";
    return distance;
}
```

The code in the `main` method will be:

```
dog1.name("Spike");
dog1.move(5);
```

My question is: how, can I do, in the `move()` method, "Dog" from the println to be replaced with the dog's name (Spike)?

Comment: `println(name + " has moved " + distance + " ft."` Of course it depends on what you named your "name" variable but you didn't show us that part.

Comment: Show the class definition. Is there a name member?

Comment: @Carcigenate what do you mean a name member? I only have a method called name.

Comment: And what does the `name()` method do? Anything like `myName = name`? If not, what use is the method?

Comment: @MateașMario Where are you storing the name in the class?

Comment: [How do getters and setters work?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2036970)

Comment: @csmckelvey Thought I can just use something like dog1.name() + " has moved" + distance + " ft." Not a variable that take the value from the method.

Comment: You can do something like that, if you provide a String to the method. If you want to use whatever name was given from a previous method call you will have to store the result of the method call somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Dog {
    private String name;

    public void setName(String nameIn) {
        name = nameIn;
    }

    public int move(int distance) {
        System.out.println(name + " has moved " + distance + " ft.");
        return distance;
    }
}

Dog dog = new Dog();
dog.setName("Spot");
dog.move(5);
```

I took the liberty of changing the name of one of your methods.  You could name the method "name" as you did and change the name of the variable (like dogName).

Comment: You have `setName` as a `String`, but it doesn't return anything.  It should probably be `void`.

Comment: Yes it should.  Thanks for catching that!  Edited.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, this is the answer to your question.

```
private String name;

public void name(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public int move(int distance)
{
    System.out.println(name+" has moved " + distance + " ft.");
    return distance;
}
```

You need to create the variable "name" in the dog class. 
Now that you have the variable "name", you set it with the method "name".
When you print in the "move" method you just write `name+` to use the variable called name.

By the way, the method "name" is a setter and would usually by standard would look like this-

```
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```